# How does SonarQube calculate the total amount of Technical Debt?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a Multi Module Maven Project which I have analyzed with SonarQube Scanner for Maven. I query the table `issues` of the database and I retrieve all the open issues `SELECT * FROM public.issues WHERE project_uuid = {project_uuid} AND status = 'OPEN';`. Although, when I sum the `effort` of all the open issues the amount of TD is different than the one the API `api/measures/component?component={project_uuid}&metricKeys=sqale_index` returns.
I am wondering i) why this is happening ii) which of the two numbers is the correct (probably the one the API returns is the correct) and iii) how could I get same number by querying the database.

Comment: _WHY_ do you want to query the database for this? You should treat the database as a black box.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Ann in her comment, database should never be used as it's not an API, the web services has been implemented for that.